# If statement with scalar conditional

Tags: perl

I am having difficulty understanding the following expression in `Perl`.

```
 for (my $attempts = 0; $attempts < $maxatt; $attempts++) {
            print "Please try again.\n" if $attempts;
            print "$prompt: ";
            $response = readline(*STDIN);
            chomp($response);
            return $response if $response;
    }
```

What does it mean to use a scalar as a conditional?  I.e. what makes it return true vs false?  I am assuming the statement reads `if ($attempts) { print ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl doesn't have a distinct concept of "Boolean value".

Per [the `perldata` manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values):

> A scalar value is interpreted as FALSE in the Boolean sense if it is undefined, the null string or the number 0 (or its string equivalent, "0"), and TRUE if it is anything else. The Boolean context is just a special kind of scalar context where no conversion to a string or a number is ever performed.

So in your example, `if $attempts` means `if $attempts > 0`.

Incidentally, this also means that something like `$attempts > 0` does not evaluate to a Boolean, because there's no such thing. Instead, per [the `perlop` manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators), operators like `>`:

> […] return `1` for true and a special version of the defined empty string, `""`, which counts as a zero but is exempt from warnings about improper numeric conversions, just as `"0 but true"` is.

(Hat-tip to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for pointing out that what they return for FALSE is not *quite* the normal empty string.)